# Ensure IQueryable<T>.Where() runs a SQL query rather than filtering in memory

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework-core

This code downloads my entire table into memory and filters there.

```cs
class Book 
{
    Id<Book> BookId;
    Id<Author> AuthorId;
}

class Person 
{
    Id<Person> PersonId;
}

class BookLookup 
{
    List<Book> GetBooksForPerson(DbContext db, Id<Person> personId) 
    {
        // yes authorId maps 1-to-1 to personId, legacy
        // codebase, can't change that right now
        return db.Books
                 .Where(b => (int)b.AuthorId == (int)personId)
                 .ToList();
    }
}
```

This code runs in SQL and only downloads the filtered rows.

```cs
class BookLookup 
{
    List<Book> GetBooksForPerson(DbContext db, Id<Person> personId) 
    {
        // yes authorId maps 1-to-1 to personId, legacy
        // codebase, can't change that right now
        var authorId = (Id<Author>)(int)personId;

        return db.Books
                 .Where(b => b.AuthorId == authorId)
                 .ToList();
    }
}
```

Both solutions compile and work, but one causes a HUGE performance problem.

How can I prevent LINQ from downloading my entire table, other than being super careful?

I'd like something like this which throws or fails to compile when it can't be converted to sql.

```cs
db.Books.WhereDb(b => (int)b.AuthorId == (int)personId)
db.Books.Where(b => (int)b.AuthorId == (int)personId, 
                FilterOption.MustRunInDb)
```

Edited to include id class and EF version:

```
public struct Id<T> : IEquatable<Id<T>>, IComparable
{
    private readonly int _value;

    private Id(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
    
    public static explicit operator int(Id<T> instance)
    {
        return instance._value;
    }

    public static explicit operator Id<T>(int value)
    {
        return new Id<T>(value);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Id<T> value1, Id<T> value2)
    {
        return value1.Equals(value2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Id<T> value1, Id<T> value2)
    {
        return !(value1 == value2);
    }

    public bool Equals(Id<T> other)
    {
        return _value.Equals(other._value);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        return obj is Id<T> type && Equals(type);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _value.GetHashCode();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints the debug string representation of this object
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var typeName = GetType().GenericTypeArguments.First().Name;
        return $"Id<{typeName}>:{_value}";
    }

    public int CompareTo(Id<T> obj)
    {
        return _value.CompareTo(obj._value);
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return 1;

        if(obj is Id<T> type)
        {
            return CompareTo(type);
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Using EF Core (v2.1.4) and a custom helper to convert `Id<T>` to int in linq-to-sql

Comment: A quick test in a `DbContext` that I happened to have handy, produces no noticeable difference in the query generated between your 2 patterns.  They both run fully on the DB for me.  Can you show how you implemented the `int` cast in `Id<T>`?  That may make some difference in how things execute.

Comment: Is this EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: My test was done in EF6.  As David's comment implies, Core may change things also.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Indeed, I suspect EF6 would actually throw errors rather than drag into RAM for code like that whereas EFCore secretly does things in memory unless you tell it not to.

Comment: I fully expected to get errors about the expression being unsupported.  I was surprised to get the result I did.

Comment: you are casting (int) everytime on (int)b.AuthorId in your first code, that's why it is taking to long, when you cast (int) , toList() and etc you are allocating memory for each entity

Comment: [This](http://share.linqpad.net/dts3cu.linq) (linqpad) is what I used to test, just in case I screwed up the test methodology somehow.  Both return the same row, and produce an identical query (including the parameterized WHERE).

Comment: What can actually run on the DB depends on the used DBS and the used EF provider, so I could imagine a general solution to be quite complicated, however EF core did some work on that front to warn if some part of a query is not executable on DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Entity Framework Core, if it cannot evaluate a clause, it will quietly evaluate everything in memory instead. Note that I said quietly because you should get a message in the log telling you it has happened.

You can change this behaviour by configuring your context, for example:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer("<connection string>")
        .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => 
            warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
}
```

See [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) for more information.

You can also do this in your startup code, for example:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    options.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => 
        warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning);
});
```

Comment: awww stupid, stupid EF. i wish they continued L2S. wait, no, i don't. it is perfect on it's own.

Comment: oh, 1 min faster than my answer. Let me put this here since I deleted mine. Applying this will break all client-side evaluated code you already coded. So you need to test every query when apply it in the first place

Comment: Thanks David! I can't believe I missed the ms doc for that.

Comment: Keep eyes on / be prepared for upcoming EF Core 3 - [LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client) :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Hallelujah!